# Oracle database returns faulty rows from stored procedure using devart in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, devart

I have an oracle database with a stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE "CalculateChats"
  (
    "In_Conf" IN NUMBER,
    "In_From" IN TIMESTAMP,
    "In_To" IN TIMESTAMP,
    "Out_Cursor" OUT "Cursor"
  ) AS
  BEGIN
  OPEN "Out_Cursor" FOR
  SELECT 
  TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR("Started", 0, 13), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI' ) as "From", 
  CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR("Started", 0, 13), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI') + 1/24 AS TIMESTAMP) as "To", 
  COUNT(*) as "Chats"
  FROM "SomeTableContainingChats" 
  WHERE "Conf" = "In_Conf" 
  AND "Started" >= "In_From"
  AND "Started" <= "In_To" 
  GROUP BY SUBSTR("Started", 0, 13) 
  ORDER BY SUBSTR("Started", 0, 13) ASC;
  END "CalulateChats";
```

When run, the stored procedure gives me a table [ From | To | NrOfOfferedChats ]
The dates are correct compared to the values.

(Example)

```
[ From                         | To                            | Chats ]
2014-09-15 08:00:00,000000000   2014-09-15 09:00:00,000000000   61
2014-09-15 09:00:00,000000000   2014-09-15 10:00:00,000000000   96
2014-09-15 10:00:00,000000000   2014-09-15 11:00:00,000000000   113
2014-09-15 11:00:00,000000000   2014-09-15 12:00:00,000000000   80
```

Now i pick it up from the C# code:

```
 using (var oraclePackage = new OraclePackage())
        {
            oraclePackage.Connection = DbConnection;
            oraclePackage.PackageName = @"CHAOS.""HiddenPackageName""";

            oraclePackage.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_Conf", conf);
            oraclePackage.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_From", from);
            oraclePackage.Parameters.AddWithValue("In_To", to);
            oraclePackage.Parameters.AddWithValue("Out_Cursor", null).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            oraclePackage.Parameters["Out_Cursor"].OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Cursor;

            oraclePackage.ExecuteProcedure(@"""CalculateChats""", oraclePackage.Parameters, true);

            using (OracleDataReader oracleReader = ((OracleCursor)oraclePackage.Parameters["Out_Cursor"].Value).GetDataReader())
            {
                if (oracleReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (oracleReader.Read())
                    {
                       oracleReader;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And the data from the oracle is oracleReader = From: 0015-09-14 01:00:00,000000000, To: 0015-09-14 02:00:00,000000000, Chats: 80

Now for the question: What could be a possible cause for the alteration from the database to the C# code, and any suggestion on how to solve it would be apreciated.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you are showing PL/SQL for a procedure that is different than what the C# is calling (CalculateChats vs GetStatistics).

Comment: In addition, what is the data type of `"Started"`?  In the code you posted, you're alternately treating it as a `timestamp` and a `varchar2`.  If you're getting different behavior calling the same code, I'd wager that your NLS settings are different in the two client applications which is leading to different behavior when various implicit data type conversions are taking place.  Fixing the code so that you're only doing explicit data type conversions would then solve the problem.

Comment: @OldProgrammer sorry had to change the name of the packages, orders from the boss :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After throwing this arround for 2 days i found out

```
CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR("Started", 0, 13), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:MI') + 1/24 AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Was converting the timestamp from 2014-09-16 08:00:00 to 16-SEP-14 02:00:00 i'm still not aware why it was converted that way but:

```
CAST(TO_CHAR("Started", 'YYYY-MM-dd HH24') || ':00:00' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Seemed to solve the problem.